# Load testing tools with dynamic input support

Tags: testing, automated-tests, load-testing, soapui

I'm trying to find a suitable load testing tool for my web application that invokes the web methods defined in a WSDL file.

I tried using soapUI, which is a great tool. I was able to accomplish most of my goals using soapUI itself, except for one.

With soapUI I need to generate the request body and then load the server with that. What I really need to perform is to dynamically build the SOAP request based on a previous SOAP response.

1. Invoke a web method
2. Parse the response which will contain an array of values
3. Pick a random item from that array and build the next SOAP request and use that to invoke another web method.
4. Repeat steps and load the server continuously

Is there any tool(preferably free) that can do this? Or any frameworks(preferably Java) that can help me do this?

Please provide your inputs.

Comment: You are saying you couldn't do that using soapUI?

Answer (score 0):

If you want free and Java, look at JMeter.

If your application is on the more complex side, then a more sophisticated tool may be called for. By complex, I mean that the scenario you need to test is more of a conversation, rather than 1 or 2 transactions.  If that is the case and you have a client software component, it may be more efficient to use a tool that can record the entire scenario as seen from a real client, rather than building up transactions from scratch.  Our [Load Tester](http://www.webperformance.com/load-testing/) does this and handles XML nicely, but it is not free.

Answer (score 0):

You may look at [Tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/).
Maybe a bit unusual for the first use but really good for stress-testing.
Was effectively used for web-services stress-testing (SOAP).
Kind of [step-by-step guide](http://beebole.com/blog/erlang/test-performance-and-scalability-of-your-web-applications-with-tsung/).